Is there a way to pass fetched data from the server side to the client side in Next 14? How can I fetch using Axios?
// navbar.tsx

import Link from "next/link";
import Container from "./ui/container";
import MainNav from "./main-nav";
import getCategories from "@/actions/get-categories";

const Navbar = async () => {
 const categories = await getCategories();
 return (
 <>
  <div className="border-b">
    <Container>
      <div className="relative px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8 flex h-16 items-center">
        <Link href="/" className="ml-4 flex lg:ml-0 gap-x-2">
          <p className="font-bold text-xl">STORE</p>
        </Link>
        <MainNav data={categories} />
      </div>
    </Container>
  </div>
 </>
);
};

export default Navbar;

// getCategories.tsx

import { Category } from "@/types";

const URL = `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/categories`;

const getCategories = async (): Promise<Category[]> => {
const res = await fetch(URL);

return res.json();
};

export default getCategories;

// app/api/[storeId]/categories

import prismadb from "@/lib/prismadb";
import { auth } from "@clerk/nextjs/server";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function POST(
 req: Request,
 { params }: { params: { storeId: string } }
) {
 try {
  const { userId } = auth();
  const body = await req.json();
  const { name, billboardId } = body;

  if (!userId) {
   return new NextResponse("Unauthenticated", { status: 401 });
  }

  if (!name) {
   return new NextResponse("Name is required", { status: 400 });
  }

  if (!billboardId) {
   return new NextResponse("Billboard ID is required", { status: 
  400 });
  }

  if (!params.storeId) {
   return new NextResponse("Store ID is required", { status: 400 
  });
  }

  const storeByUserId = await prismadb.store.findFirst({
   where: {
     id: params.storeId,
     userId,
    },
  });

  if (!storeByUserId) {
   return new NextResponse("Unauthorized", { status: 403 });
  }

  const category = await prismadb.category.create({
   data: {
     name,
     billboardId,
     storeId: params.storeId,
   },
  });

  return NextResponse.json(category);
 } catch (error) {
 console.log("[CATEGORIES_POST]", error);
 return new NextResponse("Internal error", { status: 500 });
}
}

export async function GET(
 req: Request,
 { params }: { params: { storeId: string } }
 ) {
try {
 if (!params.storeId) {
   return new NextResponse("Store ID is required", { status: 400 
});
 }

 const categories = await prismadb.category.findMany({
   where: {
     storeId: params.storeId,
   },
  });

 return NextResponse.json(categories);
 } catch (error) {
 console.log("[CATEGORIES_GET]", error);
 return new NextResponse("Internal error", { status: 500 });
 }
}

I am building a NextJS app with Prisma and Supabase for my backend, and I am trying to fetch some data stored on my server side to the client, but I am getting this "Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON" error. The file has no error, but the console sends the error above.
The server app works perfectly fine without any errors, and the /categories file also has no errors. All the necessary documents are in the code.
I have seen many developers having the same problem, and some claimed that fetching with Axios was solving the problem, but I am not used to using Axios and I think I would need some help with that.
